# How do you extract a Vector3 positions only from a world matrix in an array of positions (from Kinect)

Tags: vector, 3d, matrix, xna, kinect

I've just started building a physical camera class for the depth data you get from a Kinect. I have a Vector3 array of `[imageWidth, imageHeight]` describing the LOCAL positions I get in from the kinect (once I project them back at the FOV of the camera lens etc). I then translate, scale and rotate the whole virtual kinect camera in space.

What I'm looking to do is to extract back again the positions of the kinect camera input but in WORLD space, not LOCAL space (i.e. it's gone through the translation, scale and rotation and gives me a Vector3 for each value of the kinect in WORLD space).

Any ideas?

Comment: I also have a picture but I'm a newbie here so it won't let me post it so let me know if you want to see what I mean and I'll email it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vector3 pos = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Zero, worldMatrix);
```

Comment: Are you sure the world matrix should be inverted? If this formula is supposed to convert points from local space to world space then I think the world matrix should be left as it is.

Comment: @Andrei, I think you're correct, the invert would be for something like a ViewMatrix, fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have 3D point coordinates in the camera space you would like to convert into world space.

To do this, you need to multiply those coordinates with the camera transformation matrix. This matrix is composed of the individual transformation (translation, rotation and scale).

Be careful on the order in which you apply the transformations: translate * scale != scale * translate.

Probably you can setup your matrix like this:

```
Matrix cameraMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(cam_sx, cam_sy, cam_sz);
cameraMatrix *= Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(cam_rx));
cameraMatrix *= Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(cam_ry));
cameraMatrix *= Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(cam_rz));
cameraMatrix *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(cam_x, cam_y, cam_z);

// Now we create a point in the camera local space
Vector3 localPoint = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
Vector3 worldPoint = Vector3.Transform(localPoint , cameraMatrix);

// Now world contains the coordinates in the world space
// For example, if your camera is located at position (5,5,5) 
// and localPoint=(0,0,0) then worldPoint=(5,5,5) which seems correct.
```